# PHP: How to Fix Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been struggling with this nested array all night, so I finally decided to ask for some help on this. I am trying to correct this nested array I have below into something else. Please respond with code examples/solutions. I am not the best PHP programmer. Thank you all in advance!

**What I want it to look like:**

```
array
  0 => 
      'enginename' => string 'Engine1' (length=19)
      'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
      'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
  1 => 
      'enginename' => string 'Engine2' (length=19)
      'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
      'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
```

**What it currently looks like:**

```
Writing data... 
The total # of columns in this query are: 3 
The length of the first array is: 363 
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'enginename' => string 'Engine1' (length=19)
      1 => 
        array
          'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array
          'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array
      3 => 
        array
          'enginename' => string 'Engine2' (length=20)
      4 => 
        array
          'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
      5 => 
        array
          'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array
      6 => 
        array
          'enginename' => string 'Engine3' (length=30)
      7 => 
        array
          'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
      8 => 
        array
          'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
```

**Update 4/24 10:26am:: bwoebi's Example Output**
This is good thank you, but not 100% what I need. it removed the nested arrays but also separated all the keys again. I need the first 3 keys in one "group" like my original example shows.

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'enginename' => string 'Engine1' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array
      'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array
      'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array
      'enginename' => string 'Engine2' (length=20)
  4 => 
    array
      'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
  5 => 
    array
      'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
  6 => 
    array
      'enginename' => string 'Engine3' (length=30)
  7 => 
    array
      'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
  8 => 
    array
      'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
```

**Update 4/24 10:36am:: bwoebi's Corrected Example Output**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'enginename' => string 'Engine1' (length=19)
      'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
      'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array
      'enginename' => string 'Engine2' (length=20)
      'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
      'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array
      'enginename' => string 'Engine3' (length=30)
      'status' => string 'up' (length=2)
      'time' => string '2013-04-17 09:28:00' (length=19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as &$oldArray) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($oldArray as $subArray)
        $newArray += $subArray;
    $oldArray = $newArray;
}
```

This works under the condition that your keys don't begin every time at zero (like your example array shows it). If they do, use `array_merge`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. You finally solved my 9 hour problem!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$array = array_map(function ($v) {
    return array_map("current", $v);
}, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Engine1
            [1] => up
            [2] => 2013-04-17 09:28:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Engine2
            [1] => up
            [2] => 2013-04-17 09:28:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Engine3
            [1] => up
            [2] => 2013-04-17 09:28:00
        )

)
```

[Live Demo](http://eval.in/17456)

Comment: I know, you love array_map really, but here it won't show high performance and it's more confusing than helpful for such a simple use case.

Comment: Your code does not work actually ... http://eval.in/17458 on the performance that is micro optimization

Comment: sorry, I misread the answer; updated my answer. Yep, now it's microoptimization. But before my code was O(n) and yours is O(n*m) ... ;)